# Selecting value of dropdown on page load

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to configure my page, depending on the dropdown value that a user chose **previously**.
The problem being that if I try to do this in the `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load`, the dropdown is not yet "populated" with the saved option that the user chose previously.

In other words, using:

```
$("#mySelect").val()
```

in the `$(document).ready` results in `null`.

in the `$(window).load` results in `null`.

using:

```
$("#mySelect option:selected").text()
```

in the `$(document).ready` results in `""`.

in the `$(window).load` results in `""`.

**More information**:

The dropdown is populated with options using a generic handler that retrieves values from a look-up table in our database and dynamically builds the html using the jquery append method.

Another generic handler then retrieves the saved data as chosen previously by the user.
The user data is bound to the dropdown using a knockout view model.

All of this happens in the `$(document).ready`.

After all of this happened, I want to configure the page depending on the option previously selected by the user for the specific dropdown. By configure I mean that some controls needs to be disabled.

All of this I can do. The page also configures properly when the user choose different options in the dropdown, the problem being I am unable to determine the option selected in the dropdown after all the data is retrieved and the knockout viewmodel is bound to the controls. In other words, I am unable to configure the page depending on the saved dropdown option when the user revisits the page, because I am unable to retrieve the saved option for the dropdown in the `$(document).ready`.

If using the jquery val() method is the wrong approach in this scenario, please advise what alternative options I should explore.

Any help or advice in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting it in the `generic handler` you mentioned, **after** you populate the dropdown, not after when the document is loaded.

Comment: Perfect! That works. If you do not mind, since I am new to web development, could you explain why it works in the generic handler and not in the document.ready after the generic handler executed? I would like to understand this.

Comment: Sure. When the page has **just** been loaded, your dropdown is initially empty. Hence, that is not the right time to select one since it is still empty. As you've mentioned it yourself, and I quote "The dropdown is populated with options using a generic handler that retrieves ...", so I've simply picked up these few keywords and spotted **at which moment** you should be selecting from the dropdown. Makes sense?

Comment: Aha, yes. Thank you! A very noob mistake to make on my side =P